# Default selected in multiple Selectbox

Tags: angularjs

> This is my HTML part

```
 <select size="3"  name="selectedSaleStatus[]" multiple ng-model="selectedSaleStatus" ng-options="type.name for type in config.saleStatus" >

</select>
```

> Its my Controller

```
 $scope.saleStatus = [
            {'id': 18, 'name': 'ABC'},
            {'id': 19, 'name': 'DEF'},
            {'id': 20, 'name': 'GHI'}
        ];
```

> I want my default selected item as ABC

Comment: your model (`selectedSaleStatus`) is what is currently selected. So just write `$scope.selectedSaleStatus = $scope.saleStatus[0].name;` in your controller. If you don't know where `"ABC"` is located, then search for it with `... = $scope.saleStatus.find((x) => {return x.name="ABC"});`

Comment: ^ typo: `x.name="ABC"` should be `x.name=="ABC"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/selects

```
<button id="saleItems" type="button" placeholder="choose" ng-model="selectedSaleStatus"
                                        bs-select data-multiple="1" max-length-html="choosed" bs-options="x.id as x.name for x in saleStatus">
                                    </button>
```

And in controller

```
$scope.selectedSaleStatus = [18];
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function testcontroller($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.saleStatus = [{
            'id': 18,
            'name': 'ABC',
            'val': true
        },
        {
            'id': 19,
            'name': 'DEF',
            'val': false
        },
        {
            'id': 20,
            'name': 'GHI',
            'val': false
        }
    ];

    $scope.selected = [{
        id: 18,
        name: "ABC"
    }];

    $scope.selectedValues = [];

    $scope.$watch('selected', function(nowSelected) {
        $scope.selectedValues = [];

        if (!nowSelected) {
            return;
        }
        angular.forEach(nowSelected, function(val) {
            $scope.selectedValues.push(val.id.toString());
        });
    });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-controller="testcontroller">
   <select multiple ng-model="sales">
      <option ng-selected="{{sale.id == selectedValues}}" ng-repeat="sale in saleStatus" value="{{sale.id}}">{{sale.name}}</option>
   </select>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any other function by which we can directly do this ?

Comment: Yes..there are many ways...How you want to implement this functionality in your programme?

Comment: I did not get you...can you please specify...?this answer is not valid?

Comment: i have multiple select box, not checkbox.

Comment: i tried this in my select box,
ng-init="selectedSaleStatus='18'"

BUt its not working

Comment: what is sale.id in your example

Comment: Hey parth, Your ans is valid. but i wanted a shortest method to do it, 

only this lines  "$scope.selectedSaleStatus = [18]; "  works for me.

Anyways Thanks for so many efforts,

Comment: actually i can easily do that functionality..but think about dynamic functionality for future....you just need to update $scope.selected...by the way you get what you want :-)